# What is an undefined vector element represented as in memory?

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, initialization

I'm currently studying C and I have a question in which I have to guess what values are in the memory.
When I say, for example `long var1[1243] = {10, 1, 0, -1, -10}` and define this vector, the first 5 elements of it are already defined, but the allocated bytes that represent the remaining 1238 elements, what are they set as in memory? More specifically, are they 0? Would saying, in assembly, after defining them, `.zero <number of remaining bytes in vector>` correct?

Comment: The remaining elements are set to zero if any initialiser is provided.  Refer to ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.9 ¶21.

Comment: I am relatively new here and I'm not entirely sure how to mark 2 answers as correct, but both @fuz and Fire Lancer told me exactly what I wanted, with some added knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: "Soon" apparently meaning "before I finish typing". Nice work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By having at least some elements initialized `{10}` C will initialize all the remaining elements in the array the same as a global variable. Either numeric zero or null pointer depending on type, and in the case of arrays of structs, all members of the struct, recursively.

In C++ an empty initializer also works `long var1[1243] = {}`, but that is not allowed in C.

Comment: @fuz I think `int I{};` style syntax was meant.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I have deleted my comment because indeed, the C grammar does not have a production for `type declarator = {}`.  This is because the curly braces must always contain at least one initialiser.

Comment: It looks like GCC allows `= {}` by default, "warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]"

Comment: Thank you all for clarifying, and for the added discussion! Exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try it?

```
long var1[1243] = {10, 1, 0, -1, -10};

long so ( unsigned int x )
{
    long var2[1243] = {10, 1, 0, -1, -10};
    return(var2[x]);
}
```

Compile and disassemble

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <so>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e24ddd4d    sub sp, sp, #4928   ; 0x1340
   8:   e24dd030    sub sp, sp, #48 ; 0x30
   c:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
  10:   e3a01000    mov r1, #0
  14:   e59f203c    ldr r2, [pc, #60]   ; 58 <so+0x58>
  18:   e28d0004    add r0, sp, #4
  1c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <memset>
  20:   e3a0000a    mov r0, #10
  24:   e3a01001    mov r1, #1
  28:   e3e02000    mvn r2, #0
  2c:   e3e03009    mvn r3, #9
  30:   e98d0003    stmib   sp, {r0, r1}
  34:   e58d3014    str r3, [sp, #20]
  38:   e58d2010    str r2, [sp, #16]
  3c:   e28d3e37    add r3, sp, #880    ; 0x370
  40:   e0830104    add r0, r3, r4, lsl #2
  44:   e510036c    ldr r0, [r0, #-876] ; 0xfffffc94
  48:   e28ddd4d    add sp, sp, #4928   ; 0x1340
  4c:   e28dd030    add sp, sp, #48 ; 0x30
  50:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  54:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  58:   0000136c    andeq   r1, r0, r12, ror #6

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <var1>:
       0:   0000000a    andeq   r0, r0, r10
       4:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
       8:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
       c:   ffffffff            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xffffffff
      10:   fffffff6            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xfffffff6
    ...
```

To confirm the ... if I link it then I see zeros in .data:

```
00000000  10 40 2d e9 4d dd 4d e2  30 d0 4d e2 00 40 a0 e1  |.@-.M.M.0.M..@..|
00000010  00 10 a0 e3 3c 20 9f e5  04 00 8d e2 0e 00 00 eb  |....< ..........|
00000020  0a 00 a0 e3 01 10 a0 e3  00 20 e0 e3 09 30 e0 e3  |......... ...0..|
00000030  03 00 8d e9 14 30 8d e5  10 20 8d e5 37 3e 8d e2  |.....0... ..7>..|
00000040  04 01 83 e0 6c 03 10 e5  4d dd 8d e2 30 d0 8d e2  |....l...M...0...|
00000050  10 40 bd e8 1e ff 2f e1  6c 13 00 00 1e ff 2f e1  |.@..../.l...../.|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001000  0a 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff  |................|
00001010  f6 ff ff ff 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
0000236c
```

So for both the local and global versions gcc is at least is zero padding the rest.  But as pointed out in a comment you should see the spec, just because one compiler doesn't, it doesn't mean that is how it is supposed to work or always works.

Comment: *why not just try it?*  Probably because that doesn't tell you whether it's an implementation detail or a language rule.  Not my downvote, but you should at least include the fact that it's guaranteed, and only show the disassembly to look at how compilers choose to implement the initialization of automatic storage.

Comment: If it doesnt zero it out then that tells you something if it does then you check the spec.  It also tells you what an implementation produces.  Burn the candle from both ends to get to the middle faster.

Comment: That's a fair point; I'd upvote if you said that in your answer.

Comment: as with other uninitialized local items I was expecting the array within the function to have only the few items initialized and the rest be as found stale/garbage in memory.  I learned something too, by trying it...dont think the compiler would add code like this just for fun, implementation defined, so assume without looking its spec based...I dont write code like this so dont have to worry, and/or can now definitely avoid code like this.

Comment: another learning experience here is how to write simple functions like this that demonstrate something without being optimized away.  manipulating a compiler takes (lots of) practice, but has great benefits not just for simple useless functions that only serve to demonstrate how a compiler handles something.

Comment: Thank you, that's another way to get there, and a lot more detailed at that too. Not my downvote either, thank you for the input!